# Регулярное выражение для принадлежности к промежутку чисел

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеется такое регулярное выражение, при помощи которого проверяется принадлежность введеного года в промежуток 1900 - 2100:

```
^19\d{2}|20\d{2}|2100$
```

Не могу понять, почему оно показывает введенные варианты, а-ля `1900232323, 201233333`, как валидные. Буду благодарен, если подскажете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оно показывает введённые варианты валидными, потому что так написано регулярное выражение:

1. Либо строка, начинающаяся с подстроки "19" и следующими за ней двумя любыми цифрами
2. Либо строка, содержащая подстроку "20" и следующими за ней двумя любыми цифрами
3. Либо строка, заканчивающаяся на подстроку "2100"

Очевидно что "1900232323" попадает под пункт 1: это строка, начинающаяся с подстроки "19" и следующих за ней двух цифр.

Возможно нужный вам результат (если я правильно понял задачу) даст следующая регулярка, в которой якори начала и окончания строки вынесены за скобки группы проверки вариантов последовательностей цифр:

```
^(?:19\d{2}|20\d{2}|2100)$
```

Answer (score 0):

VSC-работает вот это -  `19\d{2}|20\d{2}|2100`

Comment: `19\d{2}|20\d{2}|2100` - в этой регулярке нет контроля количества всех символов строки...

Answer (score 0):

Предложу еще вот такой вариант...

```js
const re = /^((19|20)\d\d|2100)$/
console.log(re.test('1900'))
console.log(re.test('1911'))
console.log(re.test('2000'))
console.log(re.test('2022'))
console.log(re.test('2100'))
console.log(re.test('1900232323'))
console.log(re.test('201233333'))
```